# Insert statement SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Is there any problem in my insert as it is saying incorrect syntax near '@rating', can you help to find the mistake please as I try and can't find it.

```
    If Page.IsValid = True Then
        Dim con1 As New SqlConnection(_start)
        con1.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Feedback VALUES(@Comment, @BuyerID,@SellerID,@rating")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", UserComment.Content)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuyerID", buyerid)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellerID", sellerid)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating", Rating.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Connection = con1

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
```

Comment: Use `@rating)")` and BTW it is always better to name the columns you want to insert into as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing `)` in your query.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Feedback VALUES(@Comment, @BuyerID,@SellerID,@rating)
```